# 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found when vscode code static analysis

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code

Recently, I tried to learn opencv in C++.
I installed opencv through homebrew.
However, there's always an error in editor that says "'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found" when performing static analysis in vscode.

I've included path in c_cpp_properties.json and I think it is correct because I can run the program correctly. Besides, I can opencv the file of opencv.hpp by click the #include

Here's my code, and the error is at line 2 which says "'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
// using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
  Mat img = imread("lena.png");
  namedWindow("image", WINDOW_NORMAL);
  imshow("image", img);
  waitKey(0);
  return 0;

}
```

Can someone help me with the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: i didn't follow the link you gave, but i think `opencv2/opencv.hpp` is the correct filename, not `opencv2/open.hpp` (so file not found)

Comment: I strongly recommend against providing important information like the code and the error message with a link. They should be added directly into the question as text.

Comment: How did you compile it? You should add the flags and the libs in the command.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Yeah, I can compile it successfully by adding the flags and the libs. The problem is error in the editor of vscode.

Comment: @Andy Sorry, that's a typo when posting.

Comment: I don't know how you organize your project, using cmake or simply makefile. If you use cmake you could try cmake-tool plugin for vscode, when opening the folder it will automatically config your project and pop up a window to ask your permission to also config intellisense, to fix this problem. If you are using makefile, try adding include paths to workspace's config file. For each workspace, there is a config file, usually when something's missing, there will be a light bulb pop up to allow you to add some paths.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but a problem with opencv in arch is that it installs opencv2 inside a folder that is opencv4, to solve this problem you must make a reference as I show below:

- first do a search
  `$ cd /   and   $ sudo find . -name '*core.hpp'`
- then depending on your file path
  `sudo ln -s /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/ /usr/local/include/opencv2`
- set your route well, in my case it was not inside the premises so I removed that address
  If you are looking for more information regarding this topic you can do it from [here](https://nrsyed.com/2018/10/28/how-to-install-opencv-on-arch-linux-in-a-virtualbox-vm/)

Answer (score -1):

You can just modify 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' to 'opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp'

Comment: that is a dirty solution. a better solution would be to fix the include paths.